# How to work out 3 dimensional vector angles

Tags: physics, education, mathematical-physics, vectors

I've come across this question and cant for the life of me think how to work it out. I understand working out the angle between two vectors e.g. given, vector a(2i+3j-k) and vector b(8i-6j+2k) but am stumped when faced with the question below. Any help you can give would be of great help.

The answer is:

"find to to the nearest tenth of a degree, the angle that the vector i+11j-4k makes with 
a) the positive y-axis          and       b) the positive z-axis

P.s. the corresponding answers in the book are a)20.5 and b)109.9

Thanks

Comment: Use the definition
$$\cos \theta = \frac{\langle u, v\rangle}{\| u\| \| v\|}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  To find out the angle between a vector and a line, just find the angle between the vector and a vector that points in the same direction as the line.  So you just need to find a vector that points in the direction of the positive y-axis, and a vector that points in the direction of the positive z-axis.